# how to test input type in c programming

Tags: c, validation, user-input

the purpose is to verify the user input, and sent error message if they enter integer when I asking for string, or enter string when I asking for integer, or any other weird symbol etc.

could anyone get me a full version of the example to demonstrate how to test for:

1.test for float type ( input )
2.test for string type ( input )
3.test for character type ( input )

and under below is my code for testing integer:

```
int getAge(){
    int x;
    puts("please enter your age:\n\n");
    x = scanf("%d",&age);
    if (x == 1){
        printf("You have entered :%d",age);
        return (age);
    }
    else {
        wrongInput();
    }
}
```

Comment: You could read the whole line, and use [`strtol`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtol) to convert the string to an integer value. The `strtol` function have facilities to validate the input, including to see if all of the string was used in the conversion.

Comment: Your code isn't strict. If the input is "123ABCD" your code will accept is integer value 123. Is that what you want?

Comment: Any input is a string...

Comment: Before you write (type) one line of code, you have to _think_ about what you are trying to do. What do you think is the difference between your #2 & #3? Are you aware the `27` is a floating point number? And that `6.2 x 10^-23` is too? What will your code be looking for? Plan ahead, **not** _on-the-fly_...

Comment: Scan for string with `%s`, then analyze and convert to `int` if necessary.

Comment: Right !  my code isn't strict, sorry about it, I just start learning the c language in 2 weeks. to be honest, it really confuses me sometimes. I used to write in c++, and they are really similar to me in some aspects.

Answer (score 0):

An example for integers, with re-entering if not correct:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void)
{
    int age;
    printf("Please enter your age: ");
    while(scanf("%d", &age)!=1 || getchar()!='\n')
    {
        scanf("%*[^\n]%*c");
        printf("You must enter your age: ");
    }

    printf("You have entered: %d\n", age);

    return 0;
}
```

For floats or doubles the principle is the same.

Answer (score 0):

The question is too vague.

In C, a null terminated array of characters is called a "string". There is no prescription as to what characters are present, except that '\0' is considered to be the *useful* end of the string (in most cases, but not all.)

The string could be a series of digits ('0'-'9') that may be convertible into a number. Is a (single) leading '-' allowed to indicate negative numbers? Are spaces before and/or after the digit sequence allowed? Is *e-notation* allowed? (Where "13e3" means "13000"). Are "thousands separators" allowed? If a single '.' is typed at the end (that could be ignored), is the input invalid because it "looks like" it might be a floating point number? Where are range checks to be performed? (Not all numbers will fit into a 32/64bit integer value.) Is "a dozen" considered a number because it is commonly understood to mean 12?

The list goes on, and we thought 'integers' would be the *easy* one.

Not going to go on with this. The picture has been painted. Without even understanding the problem, it is pointless trying to write code that *might be* the *solution*.